# 403 error when trying to fetch folder content on webserver

Tags: javascript, html, directory, fetch-api, http-status-code-403

Im very new to the whole thing of web stuff.

I have a folder with images that are regularly uploaded from my local machine. On my website, these images just should be displayed in a simple grid.

So I have the following code, that, to my understanding, fetches all the folders content, takes the images and puts them into a grid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
      grid-gap: 10px;
      margin: 20px;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .grid-item {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .grid-item p {
      color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container" id="imageGrid">
  </div>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const imageGrid = document.getElementById('imageGrid');

      // Fetch the images from the "GradientImages" folder
      fetchImages();

      async function fetchImages() {
        const path = 'GradientImages/';
        const response = await fetch(path);
        const text = await response.text();
        const files = text.split('\n').filter(file => isValidImageFile(file));

        // Loop through the files and display them in the grid
        files.forEach((file, index) => {
          const imageItem = document.createElement('div');
          imageItem.className = 'grid-item';

          const img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = path + file.trim(); // Trim the file name to remove extra whitespace
          img.alt = `Image ${index + 1}`;

          const number = document.createElement('p');
          number.textContent = `Image ${index + 1}`;

          imageItem.appendChild(img);
          imageItem.appendChild(number);
          imageGrid.appendChild(imageItem);
        });
      }

      function isValidImageFile(file) {
        const validExtensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'];
        const fileExtension = file.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        return validExtensions.includes(fileExtension);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when I test it in the web, the following error message comes up in the "inspect" window

```
GET https://www.cohan-weggs.de/marc/InterfaceDesign2023/GradientImages/ 403
fetchImages @ (index):40
(anonymous) @ (index):36
```

Now I dont know, if my initial html code is wrong or if the permissions arent set up quite right.
Maybe there is also an easier alternative, that I could use.